# GameManager keeps being marked as null

Tags: unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I was writing a script for GameManager using Singleton design pattern but somehow when I run my game I get null reference exception on it. Since I am changing my scene often, I made a script where I wont be destroying GameManager and a few diffrent objects, instead I will be using DontDestroyOnLoad which is most likely the reason for the exception.

I am using this script for the GameManager which is attached to the empty gameobject in the scene.

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {
    private static GameManager instance;
    public static GameManager Instance {
        get {
            if (instance == null) {
                Debug.Log("Game Manager not found");
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    [SerializeField] private List<GameObject> objectsNotToDestroy;
    [SerializeField] private float dayAndNightTime;
    private PlayerMovement player;
    public float CurrentTime { get; set; }
    public float DayTime { get; private set; }

    private void Awake() {
        if (instance != null) {
            Debug.Log("Not null");
            objectsNotToDestroy.ForEach(Destroy);
        }
        else {
            Debug.Log("Here");
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            objectsNotToDestroy.ForEach(DontDestroyOnLoad);
        }
        PlayerMovement playerMovement = objectsNotToDestroy[1].GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();
        if (playerMovement != null) {
            player = playerMovement;
        }
        else {
            Debug.LogError("PlayerMovement script not found on object in objectsNotToDestroy list.");
        }
        DayTime = dayAndNightTime;
    }

    public void Load(int buildIndex) {
        CurrentTime += Time.time;
        SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(buildIndex);
        player.Running(false);
    }
}
```

When i run my game both "GameManager not found" and "Here" are outputed which leads me to conclusion that not destroying the gameObject that my GameManager script is attached to is making the problem. I tried some things like including/ excluding the gameObject my GameManager script is attached to but nothing I tried works and I am a bit confused why.

Comment: He Nikola can you show an example on how other scripts are referencing GameManager.instance and your hierarchy is hard to spot the issue without some context on how this is being called?

Comment: Sure, give me a moment

Comment: Here im referencing it, which of course gets null reference(I just posted a part where im referencing it, not the whole script):
public override bool GetTileAnimationData(Vector3Int location, ITilemap tilemap, ref TileAnimationData tileAnimationData) {
        tileAnimationData.animatedSprites = sprites;
        tileAnimationData.animationSpeed = sprites.Length / (2 * GameManager.Instance.DayTime);
        return true;
    }

Comment: Since im having "GameManager not found" log, the problem must be with the script itself. I doubt other scripts have any problems.

Comment: To save headaches, I usually add a `FindObjectOfType` in the getter if the instance is null, and set the instance to that.   `Instance {get { if (instance == null) instance = FindObjectOfType<GameManager>();  if (instance == null) Debug.Log("Object Doesnt Exist"); return instance; }`.  You can replace that debug with object creation as well, which is nice in some cases.

Comment: ChatGPT advised me the same thing so I did and i think it works. Now i have another problem so can you come to this section later because i have to go to sleep?

Comment: which concrete line causes the NullReferenceException?

Comment: This GameManager.Instance isnt set before GetTileAnimationData getting me null reference

Answer (score 0):

To get predictable behaviour for your singleton try this:

- Set up script execution order so your GameManager is instantiated before any other script that will reference it: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html
- Create "init" type scene, which is never unloaded and has your GameManager script on top level game object. Load all your other scenes as additive, without unloading "init" scene.

Comment: How to reference objects I dont want to destroy when loading new scenes. Do I put them in init to since I cant reference them from init if they are in game scene

Comment: Thank you for this solution, it works but I dont know what to do with this dont destroyonload gameObjects

Comment: With things you already used like singleton pattern

Comment: I think I did that but I dont know how to reference GameManager from init to game scene. Im using this line of code: GameManager.Instance.Load(buildIndex); in game scene and having gamemanager in init scene so it doesnt get referenced well

Comment: destroyonload if fine to be left there, it will do no harm.

Comment: Still I dont know how to get this gamemanager script from init scene to game scene

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Artur Karpiński I made GameManager fully functional by moving it along with some of my game objects to a seperate scene, making those game objects DontDestroyOnLoad and using this modified script( simplyfing it didn't work):

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {
private static GameManager instance;
public static GameManager Instance {
    get {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = FindObjectOfType<GameManager>();
            if (instance == null) {
                Debug.Log("Could not find GameManager object");
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}

[SerializeField] private float dayAndNightTime;
private PlayerMovement player;
[SerializeField] private List<GameObject> objectsNotToDestroy;
public float CurrentTime { get; set; }
public float DayTime { get; private set; }
private AsyncOperation sceneLoadingOperation;
private bool called = false;

private void Awake() {
    DayTime = dayAndNightTime;
    sceneLoadingOperation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(1, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
}

private void Update() {
    if (sceneLoadingOperation.isDone && !called) {
        called = true;

        if (instance != this) {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
            SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync("Init");
            instance = this;
            objectsNotToDestroy.ForEach(DontDestroyOnLoad);
            player = objectsNotToDestroy[2].GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();
        }
    }
}

public void Load(int buildIndex) {
    CurrentTime = Time.time;
    SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(buildIndex);
    player.Running(false);
}
```

}